Eureka-Spring Boot Microservice
spring:
application:
name: apigatewaymanagement-service
main:
web-application-type: reactive
eureka:
client:
fetch-registry: false
register-with-eureka: false
service-url:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
server:
port: 8761
How can I fix it?
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot bootstrap eureka server :
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.servlet.ServletContext.setAttribute(String, Object)" because "context" is null

Please add more details. Even code repository.
